# Quick sort explanation on an assignment

Tags: java, sorting, pivot, quicksort

I am writing a specific variant of `quicksort` class. However; the directions on this variant of quick sort is confusing me. I have written the code for quick sort, but I do not understand the description. Can anyone help me understand this description means for the variant so I can finalize it?



Description: implement a variant of quicksort with pivots chosen according to pivot_pos. That is, whenever the quicksort makes a recursive call to quicksort a subarray (A, p, r), it chooses as the pivot min(p+pivot,r).

To my interpretation, this is saying to include within the if statement of `quicksort` a `int` value of          
`min(p + pivot, r)`. It would partition the array with the pivot representing this value, and quicksorting the array with this value as well.

```
public static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r)
{
    int x = a[r];
    int i = p - 1;
    for( int j = p; j <= r - 1; j++)
    {
        if(a[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            swap(a, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(a, i + 1, r);
    return i + 1;
}

public static void quick_sort(int[] a, int p, int  r)
{
    if(p < r)
    {
        int q = partition(a, p, r);
        quick_sort(a, p, q - 1);
        quick_sort(a, q + 1, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Such a long story without any question mark.

Comment: Added one question mark

Comment: I believe you're on the right way. During QS you have to chose a pivot element and partition the array (and do it recursively). Commonly the first/last element is chosen, but there are several variants. Your description says you should use a specific element (that is `pivot` positions away from the lower `p` index).